# How can I fix my dosbox? It freezes and auto closed whenever I use DOS DEBUG's g command

Tags: assembly, x86-16, dosbox

I hope you can help me. I tried using DOSBOX for handling assembly language but whenever I use the G command in `debug` it does not produce results and the DOSBOX freezes/does not respond until it auto closes itself. How can I fix this?

[image: here is the sample picture.]

Comment: Which version of Debug is that? Also, please copy the text shown by the VM, do not show a screenshot of it.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I'm not aware of any Debug that modifies `ip` from assembling, the `g` command should work. For troubleshooting OP could try running one or several `t` commands though. Or an `r` command first, of course.

Comment: You are right @ecm . It had been a while. I realized though that the `int 20` may not be properly exiting as a DOS COM program from withing DEBUG and if there is buffered output possibly you wouldn't see anything and `int 20` sends you into lalaland. I wonder what would happen if he used `mov ah, 4c` `int 21` instead of `int 20`

Comment: I seem to recall that when DEBUG is launched without a program there is no Program Segment Prefix and `int 20` requires CS == PSP segment. Without a proper PSP the `int 20` hangs or crashes DOSBox eventually. If there is buffered output that hasn't been flushed before int 20h is reached it probably appears as if the program did nothing.

Comment: Where from did you obtain this `DEBUG` binary?  And yes, try just using `ret` to end your program.

Comment: @fuz: `retn` to end a program also relies on the stack to hold a zero word and then generally the `int 20h` at the start of the PSP (segment of which equals `cs`). If there is anything to this theory then interrupt 21h service 4Ch would be the way to go. (Yes, @MichaelPetch, `int 20h` may require `cs` = PSP.) But the function 09h call should not buffer output, there is no such mechanism built into DOS's stdout. Agreed that we want to know which Debug program this is.

Comment: @ecm iirc if you `RET` out of a program running under `DEBUG`, it just returns back to the debugger.  Maybe `DEBUG` places an appropriate return address on the stack.

Comment: What version of DEBUG is given when you do `DEBUG /?`

Comment: @fuz : it depends on the version of DEBUG. The DEBUG that came with Windows NTVDM has some peculiar characteristics as I recall. I know there are version fof DEBUG out there that don't have a PSP and if you do a RET the 00 00 on the stack will direct to a non existent PSP that lacks the `int 20h` instruction that exist a DOS COM program. But there are versions of DBUG out there that don't even accept `int 20h` if CS isn't pointing at a PSP. I highly recommend to avoid problems to use AH=4ch, int 21h to exit.

Comment: Of course if you load a COM program from disk all these issues would disappear because a proper PSP would have been created when DEBUG loaded the COM program.

Comment: I've finally managed to duplicate this behaviour with the DEBUG clone version 0.98 . What is even more interesting is that there almost appears to be a bug in the debugger since it seems to work if the string is terminated with 0d 0a but fails as described here when the line terminator are not there. Very odd.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: You mean [FreeDOS Debug version 0.98](https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/fddebug/file/version-0.98/debug.asm)? Works fine in a dosemu2 instance on our server. I don't see anything obvious. Maybe I can reproduce it in DOSBox later. How do you feed the debugger strings that are terminated by different linebreak sequences like 0Dh 0Ah? It should [get lines from interrupt 21h function 0Ah](https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/fddebug/file/version-0.98/debug.asm#l4809) which always terminates with a lone CR.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I just tested running DOSBox 0.74-3 (from a Debian package) and using debug.com from [the original DEBUG098.zip](https://pushbx.org/ecm/download/fddebug/DEBUG098.zip) archive. No crash, after the `G` command the next line shows "Hello World!-" (Trailing dash is the debugger's prompt.) Running a `G` command a *second time* does crash, because apparently the debugger does not properly re-initialise things. Turns out, [int22 is only set when loading a program](https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/fddebug/file/version-0.98/debug.asm#l3407), empty processes get `debug22`, the wrong entrypoint.

Comment: This particular bug was fixed [in FreeDOS Debug version 0.99i](https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/fddebug/rev/9bd81288c2f6) which initialises the empty process properly, the first time around. It is the first version that will show the "Program terminated normally." message upon assembling `int 20` and then running `g` once.

Comment: OP: Please run the `?` command in your Debug and/or tell us where it is from.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, @ecm, this is the code my instructor gave to us

e200 "Hello world!$"
a100
mov ah, 09
mov dx, 200
int 21
int 20
g

I also asked him why my DosBox keeps crashing after I use g-command but he also don't know the answer :(

Comment: @MichaelPetch & ecm: I've downloaded my debug from this link
[https://github.com/aks84/asm?fbclid=IwAR1OTT_8HMsOnhe5_t2aLGe0uo-D1EuPR1tTs7fE4lXueF_MkZERLC8ZrnE]

Comment: @ecm: = I tried using debug.com from the link you shared and it worked! thank u so much!

Comment: @ZachMendes: I don't recommend using such an old version, especially seeing as it has issues recreating a process after terminating one once. Instead, consider [DOS Debug version 1.28](https://github.com/Baron-von-Riedesel/DOS-debug/releases/tag/v1.28) (the latest release of the original FreeDOS Debug), or my fork [lDebug release 4](https://pushbx.org/ecm/download/ldebug/ldebug4.zip).

Comment: @MichaelPetch: The Debug from that repo checks for DOS version 5.00 and crashes in dosemu2 the same as shown in the question. If I replace `int 20` by `mov ax, 4C00` then `int 21` I also get a crash but the message is shown at least. If I load a .com file instead of assembling a program in an empty process then it works as expected.

Comment: Also when assembling instead of loading a program, interrupt 21h service 62h returns Debug's PSP as the current PSP. And its parent and parent return address are both set up to return into the shell. Not sure why it crashes though, instead of just returning to the shell.

Comment: I debugged this MS Debug (using callver and a current lDebug) some, resulting in this log: https://pushbx.org/ecm/test/20220503/debug.txt The part where lDebug regains control is clearly [in the DEXIT function](https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/msdos2/file/05669dfa5edd/v2.0/source/debug/DEBCOM2.ASM#l421), though what's seen in the log differs a bit from what I linked in the MS-DOS version 2 sources here. Anyway, skipping the instructions which install MS Debug's int1 and int3 handlers results in the 21.4C00 call succeeding. As in, it ends the entire MS Debug process. Still unsure about the crash.

Comment: @ecm - I have a similar problem running [this fire animation](https://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/fire/Fire.html).  It runs perfectly using original ms-debug under G command first time round but running G command second time freezes when exiting the code.  I tried using your latest debug 1.28 version using link shared above.  Also tried various exit combinations a) RET,  b) INT 20, c) MOV AX,004C followed by INT 21.  All had same freeze issues in both ms-debug and debug 1.28.  Was there a workaround/fix to this bug/defect?  Not a big deal, but but would be great to resolve!  Thanks!

Comment: @AssadEbrahim I'm confused as to what exactly you enter in the debugger. Did you build the executable as instructed then run `debug fire.com`? Or did you run the program just after assembling / entering it? By "ms-debug" do you mean the original from some MS-DOS or [my fork of the MS-DOS v2 Debug](https://pushbx.org/ecm/download/msdebug.zip)? Also [try lDebug](https://pushbx.org/ecm/download/ldebug.zip), the only debugger that I actively maintain. A better format for this question would probably be email or [our forum](https://bttr-software.de/forum/)

Comment: @ecm - for completeness, I'll answer here, and then if it gets complicated I'll move to the forum (thanks for the link):  1/ I entered the machine code into a .com file (fire.com) and loaded it into debug in the standard way (nfire.com l),   2/ by ms-debug I mean the original 16-bit executable from MS-DOS run in DOSBox emulator,  3/ after running it once and seeing the fire animation, I pressed a key to exit the animation and return to debug.  Reset registers cleanly (ax, cx, sp, cs, ip), then pressed G again to re-run.  Animation runs again, but now attempting to exit causes debug to freeze.

Comment: @AssadEbrahim In lDebug it should work to run once, enter an L command, and run again. Original MS-DOS Debug is seriously broken in its process model. My fork MSDebug should be better regarding this. In both lDebug and MSDebug if you run G again after the debuggee process terminated, you get another immediate termination as the empty process that's created is initialised with a single `retn`

Answer (score -1):

I would avoid int 20. Kip R. Irvine : assembly language for the ibm pc. page 647 dos interrupts .. 20 : [Terminate program.Terminate the current program. ( int 21h function 4Ch should be used instead )]
your program would change to :
debug
-e200 "Hello World!$"
a 100
xxxx:0100 mov ah,09
xxxx:0102 mov dx,200
int 21
mov cx,4c00
int 21